# Convert datepicker date to ISO format with moment.js

Tags: momentjs, bootstrap-datepicker

My task is to use a datepicker to pick a date in the prescribed format, eg(MM-DD-YYYY) and pass it to the server as ISO formatted.

While it test the output the ISO formatted date is one day behind.

For example

If i select

```
07-13-2015
```

My Output ISO format is

```
ISO format is :2015-07-12T18:30:00.000Z
```

Here you can see date is 13 but the output date is 12

I am from India. I tried with zone and utcOffset, ended up with no results. How do i set it right

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/n6g30zvj/)

**js code**

```
$('#datetimepicker1').on("dp.change",function(e){
        var selectedDate = $('#datetimepicker1').find("input").val();
        selectedDate = moment(selectedDate,"MM-DD-YYYY");
        $(".temp").text(moment(selectedDate).toISOString());
    });
```

I do have a hidden field which value will be updated on change and that will be processed in the server. No issues on that.

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#datetimepicker1').on("dp.change",function(e){
        var selectedDate = $('#datetimepicker1').find("input").val();
        selectedDate = moment(selectedDate,"MM-DD-YYYY");
        $(".temp").text(selectedDate.toISOString());
    });
```

Your selectedDate is already a moment object so you do not need to feed it back into another moment.

Example:

```
var test = '07-13-2015'
var mtest = moment(test,"MM-DD-YYYY")
mtest.toISOString()
"2015-07-13T06:00:00.000Z"
```

Comment: can you spot the difference between your code and my code please. And the date from datepicker is not coming as moment object. It was showing invalid date. I made a jsfiddle.Any my question is if selected 13 the ISO string say 12... please have a look into my jsfiddle.

Comment: After playing with your JSFiddler and re-reading your question, I think you may be running into an issue with the timezone change.  I think you are seeing the date change due to the fact that India has enough time difference between UTC.  The reason I think this is I am unable to duplicate your issue (locally or in JSFiddler).

Comment: My comment about selectDate already being a moment is with regards to the third line: this turns selectedDate into a moment => selectedDate = moment(selectedDate,"MM-DD-YYYY");  So on your forth line, you are putting a moment object into a new moment object => $(".temp").text(moment(selectedDate).toISOString());

Comment: got it. I got the point of the time difference. how to get it done properly with UTC("5.30") as per documentation of moment.js didnt work for me.

Comment: Or as a advise shall we leave it to the server guys to take care of the conversion as everything is recorded with respect to server timing.

Answer (score 0):

Your could try converting the date format to UTC at once.

```
selectedDate = moment(selectedDate).utc('MM-DD-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html, if you pass a string like '07-13-2015', it means Midnight of 13th July 2015. Now, if you use toISOString function, it will convert it to UTC by default. To not convert it to UTC, just pass a parameter true in the toISOString function. ([Moment.js docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/))

For example:

```js
var date = '07-13-2015';
date = moment(date,'MM-DD-YYY');
console.log(date.toISOString(true));
```

This way, moment will not convert the date to UTC.